# How to Handwrite combineReducer with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm learning redux with typescript.
Until I hit combineReducer,

```
export const reducerBase= combineReducers({
  stateA: reducerA,
  stateB: reducerB,
  stateC: reducerC
});
```

is working fine, but I can't manage to hand write it.
currently what I'm trying to do is

```
function initialState(): BaseState{
  return {
    a: [],
    b: [],
    c: []
  };
}

type AllActions = AAction | BAction | CAction;


// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
function isAAction(arg: any) {
  return arg.includes('_A');
}

export function reducerBase(
  state: BaseState= initialState(),
  action: AllActions 
): BaseState{
  if (isAAction(action.type)) {
    return { ...state, a: reducerA(state.a, action) }; // here the problem
  }

  return state;
}
```

type AllActions is not assignable to type AAction,

How should I proceed?

It's working,

```
export function reducerBase(
  state: BaseState= initialState(),
  action: AllActions 
): BaseState{
  a: reducerA(state.a, action as AAction);
  b: reducerB(state.b, action as BAction);
  c: reducerC(state.c, action as CAction);
  return {a,b,c};
}
```

while BAction is called on reducerA and reducerC, they do nothing and just returned their own state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because `isAAction` function just returns boolean, there is no way Typescript could know that this boolean indicates action type.

First solution - just cast it to AAction:

```
return { ...state, a: reducerA(state.a, action as AAction) };
```

Second solution - change `isAAction` method into typeguard, then Typescript will know that this function returns true when `AAction` is passed as argument

```
function isAAction(action: any): arg is AAction {
  return action.type.includes('_A');
}

// ...

if (isAAction(action)) {
   return { ...state, a: reducerA(state.a, action) };
}
```

EDIT: Reffering to your comment. I personally wouldn't use `reducerBase` reducer at all and just used the following structure. Action type will determine which reducer should react on given action.

```
const reducers = {
  stateA: reducerA,
  stateB: reducerB,
  stateC: reducerC
};

export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers(reducers)
);

export function reducerA(state = new StateA(), action: AAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AActionType.SOME_ACTION: return {
      ...state,
      // some changes based on action
    }

    case AActionType.OTHER_ACTION: return {
      ...state,
      // some changes based on action
    }

    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks.
Do you know any better approach better than what I do?

Comment: I updated my answer. Didn't used redux a lot so I'm not saying my proposal is the best practise.

Comment: Take a look at typescript-fsa (https://github.com/aikoven/typescript-fsa). It works fine with redux and helps you having your action payload correctly typed. I used it with Redux (+ redux observable + typescript-fsa-reducers + typescript-fsa-redux-observable) and it worked really fine. For now, I did not found a better solution for TypeScript + Redux.

Comment: The update actually going backward, ahahah,
I'm able to do combineReducers, but got curious to handwrite it.
reducerBase is my own named function.

But thanks to you, I've come to some solution.